# how to upload heavy files in sharepoint library?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a library in which videos are going to store. but when i am going to upload media file greater than 50 mb, it gives me an error like 'An unexpected error has occured'.

so my question is how can i upload heavy media files as document in sharepoint 2010 library.

Comment: Please provide relevant code, and/or more detailed error output.

Comment: how are you uploading ? HTTP Post ? HTTP PUT ? WebDAV ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several places where such a limit might be configured:

**For WebDAV** it is in the registry (Key `FileSizeLimitInBytes`) at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters` which is a **client-side limit (default 50 MB)**!

**For IIS** it is in the web.config of the site (`<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="XX" />`)

**For Sharepoint itself**:
Configure maximum file size for a SharePoint web application

```
In Central Administration, in Application Management, click Manage web applications.
NoteNote

Select the application (for example, SharePoint - 80).

On the Web Applications ribbon, click the down arrow on the General Settings button.

Click General Settings.

Scroll to Maximum Upload Size.

Click OK.
```

Comment: I tried that way but it gives me an error Error 
An unexpected error has occurred. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 1a32411b-f57a-401c-bd6f-dadc2a991ad9 

Date and Time: 9/8/2011 9:55:41 AM

Comment: that is hard diagnose remotely - any other information you can give ?